# Kafka spends too much time to start reading

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

Currently I am working with the Confluent kafka nuget package, but do not use the Confluent platform itself (https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet).

According to the application needs, it is required to create a consumer, get the first message, and shutdown the consumer. The whole cycle should be done as quick as possible (up to 1 sec).
Issue I have faced with - a lot of poll() cycles required to read the first message (data is already produced and exists in topic):

about 8 seconds when using subscribe() method (because of the rebalancing)
about 5 seconds when using assign() (without the rebalancing)

I tried a lot of configuration things on the consumer side (because producer is not involved into it), but nothing helped.
Is it expected behavior? Maybe something need to be configured on the broker side?

You can find the code of my simple consumer below:

```
class Program
{
    private static Dictionary<string, object> _config =>
        new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "group.id", "test-consumer" },
            { "enable.auto.commit", false },
            { "bootstrap.servers", "192.168.56.102:9092" },
            { "default.topic.config", new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    { "auto.offset.reset", "smallest" }
                }
            }
        };


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        var consumer = new Consumer<Ignore, string>(_config, null, new StringDeserializer(Encoding.UTF8));
        consumer.Assign(new List<TopicPartition> {new TopicPartition("TestQueue", 0)});
        Message<Ignore, string> msg = null;
        bool cancel = false;
        consumer.OnMessage += (sender, message) =>
        {
            msg = message;
            cancel = true;
        };

        while (!cancel)
        {
            consumer.Poll(100);
        }

        consumer.CommitAsync(msg);
        consumer.Dispose();
        sw.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the broker version ?

Comment: version is 0.11.0.0

Comment: Related/same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223765/kafka-consumer-startup-delay-confluent-dotnet   ?